# Error: file does not start with RIFF id on Colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to record audio in colab and convert that into text using speech recognition module. I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61607901/is-there-any-way-to-input-microphone-on-azure-notebooks-google-collab) to record in colab and it works fine, if i download the wav file, i can hear everything clearly. Just that when i load my audio file for speech recognition module, it gives this error:

```
Error: file does not start with RIFF id
```

This id the code that gives the error:

```
  audiox = record()
  
  inp = sr.AudioFile(audio)

# convert mp3 file to wav file

  with inp as file:
      audio = r.record(file)
      text=r.recognize_google(audio)
      print(text)
  return text
```